# How to add a privilege to an account in Windows?

Tags: windows, security, permissions, wcf, named-pipes

Given:

- A VM running Windows 2008
- I am logged on there using my domain account (SHUNRANET\markk)
- I have added the "Create global objects" privilege to my domain account:
- The VM is restarted (I know logout/logon is enough, but I had to restart)
- I logon again using the same domain account. It seems still to have the privilege:
  [image]
- I run some process and examine its Security properties using the Process Explorer. **The account does not seem to have the privilege**:
  [image]

This is not an idle curiousity. I have a real problem, that without this privilege the named pipe WCF binding works neither on Windows 2008 nor on Windows 7! Here is an interesting discussion on this matter - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b71cfd4d-3e7f-4d76-9561-1e6070414620.

Does anyone know how to make this work? Thanks.

**EDIT**

BTW, when I run the process elevated, everything is fine and the process explorer does display the privilege as expected:

[image]

But I do not want to run it elevated.

**EDIT2**

I equally welcome any solution. Be it configuration only or mixed with code.

**EDIT3**

I have posted the same question on MSDN forums and they have redirected me to this page - http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;132958. I am yet to determine the relevance of it, but it looks promising.

Notice also that it is a completely coding solution that they propose, so whoever moved this post to the ServerFault - please reinstate it back in the StackOverflow.

Comment: Please explain why the question should be closed. The solution can be programmatic, which fits perfectly with this site.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't get the impression the solution should be programmatic. I only saw the screenshots and thought it's a server configuration issue. But for someone who is into Windows security, it's probably obvious you ask about a programmatic solution, isn't it?

Comment: @Ladislav - then by all means mark it as the answer :-).

Comment: @Grzegorz - I am looking for all solutions. Both configuration and programmatic. And because a programmatic solution is very likely this question belongs here. Of course, configuration only solution is most welcome as well.

Comment: You have to run elevated in order to enable certain privileges; there is no way around this.

Comment: This is not true. The NETWORK SERVICE account has this privilege enabled. Yet it never runs elevated.

Comment: If you included some code, library references, or API references, it would make your question less likly to be flagged or down-voted. Lack of any programming references makes users view it as not programming.

Comment: Accounts like NETWORK SERVICE get special treatment from the operating system.  In the general case a normal (non-elevated) user account is never going to have those privileges present in its token.

Comment: Please make sure that you are member of domain admin group

Comment: Please, explain why.

Comment: @mark "Yet it never runs elevated." this is not true. NETWORK SERVICE does run elevated. that's the point of that account: it lets you run services on the local machine that require elevated rights and be a network server.

Answer (score 1):

If your NamedPipe WCF Service needs to be hosted in the Global objects to communicate between sessions I'd build it as a separate Windows Service and let the your other applications  communicate with each other through the new Windows Service that will be hosting your NamedPipe WCF Service.

Answer (score 0):

It because of a feature called UAC. Why don't you just turn it off?
Then you won't need to run these tasks elevated, your account will just have this security permissions when you run the program normally.

See here for an article I found about UAC and problems it can have with certain programs. It is specifically ansering a problem about Explorer but the principle still applies and it explains how UAC works and possible work arounds. http://think-like-a-computer.com/2011/05/11/uac-access-denied-on-folders-for-administrators-windows-2008/